What's the best compression algorithm for sets of images that share conceptual similarities?
I want to compress several hundred images together into a single file. The images are all scans of Magic: The Gathering cards, which means they have large blocks of similar color and share many similarities across images like the frame and text box.
I want to take advantage of the similarities between pictures, so formats like JPG and PNG that only consider a single image at a time are useless. Algorithms like DEFLATE also are bad here, because if I understand correctly they only consider a small "context window" that's tiny compared to a set of images a few hundred MB in size.
A simple diffing approach like that mentioned here would probably also not work very well, since the similarities are not pixel-perfect; there are relatively few pixels that are exactly the same color between images, they're just similar.
The video compression suggestion in the same thread would require me to put the images in a specific order, which might not be the optimal one; a better algorithm would itself determine which images are most similar to each other.
The best lead I have so far is something called "set redundancy compression", but I can't find very much information about it; that paper is almost 20 years old, and given how common it is to need to store large sets of similar images, I'm sure much more work has been done on this in the internet age.
Set redundancy compression also appears to be lossless, which I don't want; I need a really high compression ratio, and am ok losing details that aren't visible to the naked eye.
